# Error al mostrar la fecha en Firefox, Safari "NaN, undefined, NaN"

Tags: javascript, html

Espero me puedan apoyar con este inconveniente que estoy teniendo, lo que pasa que quiero mostrar una fecha, ese dato me lo proporcionan mediante una URL la cual yo consumo, pero en los navegadores firefox y safari no me los muestra correctamente me los muestra de las siguiente manera:

**" NaN de undefined del NaN "**

Anexo el codigo que como lo estoy mostrando

```
<script>
    $(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://miurl.php",
            dataType: "html",
            // async: "false",
            data: {
                autor: 32,
                metodo: "lista",
                limite: 3
                }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            let result = JSON.parse(msg);
            // console.log(result)
            let html = '';
           
            $(result).each(function(index,item){

            let fecha = item.fecha;
            var meses = new Array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
            var f = new Date(fecha);


                html += '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                        '<img src="'+item.imagen+'" width="100%" height="250px"><br>'+
                        '<div class="texto-noticia"><span style="color: #001e96;">'+f.getDate() + ' de ' + meses[f.getMonth()] + ' del ' + f.getFullYear()+'</span><br>'+item.titulo+'</div>'+
                        '<div id="nota-completa">'+
                            '<a title="'+item.titulo+'" href="'+item.url+'" target="_blank">'+
                                '<img id="img-nota-completa" src="/leer-nota-completa.png">'+
                            '</a>'+
                        '</div><br>'+
                        '</div>';

            });
            $('#noticia').append(html);
        });
    });

    
</script>
<div id="noticia" class="row"  style="height: 20px;"></div>
```

Espero me puedan apoyar con este detalle que estoy presentando :(

Comment: en que formato te llega la fecha?

Comment: el formato me parece que es el siguiente: AAAA/MM/DD

Comment: ese formato es correcto. Puedes poner lo que tienes en `result` o `item`?

Comment: Si haces `f = new Date("algo inválido")` , `f.getDate()` va a retornar `NaN` , tendrías que hacer `console.log(item.fecha)` y verificar que es lo que hay ahí.

Comment: 2021-07-05,
2021-06-30,
2021-06-25 esas fechas son las que me muestra

Comment: En crome, opera si me muestra la fecha bien, solo en Firefox y Safari no me los muestra correctamente